# Custom sign out page, not removing cookies

Tags: development, custom, application-pages

In my custom login script I'm creating a cookie that can be read by other company web applications. The code for this is:

```
setCookie("Communities", "LoggedIn=true&NSContactId=" + NSContactId, ".mydomain.com");
```

where

```
public static void setCookie(string cookieName, string cookieValue, string cookieDomain)
{
    HttpCookie newCookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
    newCookie.Value = cookieValue;
    newCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
    newCookie.Domain = cookieDomain;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(newCookie);
}
```

I need to remove this custom cookie when someone logs out of SharePoint, and I'm having trouble with this.

I created a custom signout page (mylogout.aspx), and replaced the default one with this custom one, using the following:

```
Set-SPCustomLayoutPage -Identity SignOut -RelativePath "/_layouts/mylogout.aspx" -WebApplication "http://sp.mydomain.com"
```

and "mylogout.aspx" uses this code:

```
<%
HttpCookie CommunitiesCookie = new HttpCookie("Communities");
CommunitiesCookie.Value = null;
CommunitiesCookie.Domain = ".mydomain.com";
CommunitiesCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(CommunitiesCookie);
Response.Redirect("/_layouts/signout.aspx");
%>
```

I know the code is being run (I can put in a line of code to write to a log file, and it does so), but the cookie doesn't get removed. I've used this code in non-SharePoint sites before, and it works there, so I'm left assuming that something in SharePoint is stopping this from working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you used a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) to view the HTTP traffic and the requests the browser is making? It might be worth checking to see if the browser is requesting /_layouts/signout.aspx and redirecting back to the login page and reauthenticating. What type of security do you have on signout.aspx vs mylogout.aspx?

Comment: I've not forgotten about this question, I've just had zero time to look at it recently. I do use Fiddler, but I didn't notice that there was any odd redirecting going on. signout.aspx is the ootb page, so I'm not really sure what security is in use, but being in the _layouts folder I suspect you have to be signed in initially to use it, though no special permissions. my custom logout.aspx has no special permissions added via roles/groups, etc but is still in the _layouts folder, so it's quite possible that the user is being re-signed in, as you suggest.

Comment: ... However, the main issue of removing custom cookies shouldn't be impacted by this